# Remove spaces bootstrap 3 grid system

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid

I have a problem I cant remove spaces between images. Im using bootstrap 3 grid system. I starded with bootstrap today. Can someone help me ? Thanks

```
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="col-lg-3">
<img src="images/1.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3">
<img src="images/2.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3">
<img src="images/3.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3">
<img src="images/4.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
</div>    
</div>


<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="col-lg-3">
<img src="images/5.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3">
<img src="images/6.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3">
<img src="images/7.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3">
<img src="images/8.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
</div>
</div>
```

Here is my example http://stanislavknopp.net/test/

Comment: There is no longer a `row-fluid` in Bootstrap 3

Answer (score 1):

Create a special CSS class and remove the padding..

```
.no-gutter [class*="col-lg-"] {
    padding-left:0;
    padding-right:0;
}
```

Here's an example: http://bootply.com/73960